# How to access a control's properties via Windows API in Delphi ?

Tags: windows, delphi, keyboard, controls, system

I am using delphi's virtual keyboard (TTouchkeyBoard) for system wide typing. 
I have a form with only the keyboard in it, nothing else.
When the extended windows style WS_EX_NOACTIVATE is set, the form never gets the focus and keystrokes are sent to the control which has the focus, system wide.
Until here everything works fine.

Now I want the keyboard to recognize, if an editable control was selected. The keyboard should pop up if an edit control was selected and hide if a control was selected which couldn't accept keyboard input, e.g. a button.

Therefore i use a global windows hook to get all of the WM_SETFOCUS messages. These messages contain the source and the target handle. So i got the handle of the control which will gain keyboard focus.
I get a TWinControl object by using the Windows function FindControl() on my handle, but how can I access the control's properties to identify it as a (non-)editable control?

Comment: Cast the `TWinControl` as the appropriate control type, and read its properties.

Comment: @Jerry the control is in a different process

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better of detecting if a caret is visible or not where the keyboard focus currently is. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application

Comment: Sorry, I think I said it wrong above. I get a handle to the WINDOW from setfocus message. Now I don't know how to get the focused child whose properties i would like to know, in that window.

Comment: You are going to need to us the automation framework to do this. The automation framework allows applications that use widely different GUI toolkits to present a uniform API to external automation programs. This is how accessibility tools are built.

Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Most (if not all) controls accept keyboard input. Even a button accepts SPACE (and possibly RETURN) key, as well as Alt+HotKey (accelerator key). Don't know if this is important in your case, though...

Comment: @David i don't think that I can use the automation framework in Delphi, do I?

Comment: Yes. It has a COM interface. It is the platform automation framework.